# Blinking JLabel for Wordle-like game?

Tags: java, swing

I would like to implement a blinking effect on a JLabel in a wordle knockoff I'm making. I think this will involve using `javax.swing.Timer` but I'm not sure how I would implement this. The game panel consists of a 5*6 grid (like worlde) of JLabels. I would like them to blink between dark gray and light gray. What should I do? Here is my code so far:

```
package projects23;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Wordle {
    File wordList = new File("words.txt");
    File allWords = new File("words.txt");
    JLabel entry[][] = new JLabel[6][5];
    int guessNum = 0;
    int letIndex = 0;
    char lastLetter = ' ';
    String guessArray[] = { "", "", "", "", "" };
    HashMap<Character, Integer> freq = new HashMap<>();
    HashMap<Character, Integer> revert = new HashMap<>();
    String targetWord;
    MyFrame frame;
    KeyListener list;

    Scanner reader;
    Scanner checker;

    public Wordle() {
        pickWord();
        setFreq();
        revert.putAll(freq);
        initGUI();

    }

    private void pickWord() {
        try {
            reader = new Scanner(wordList);
            Random rand = new Random();
            int pick = rand.nextInt(5740);
            for (int i = 0; i < pick; i++) {
                targetWord = reader.nextLine().toUpperCase();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void setFreq() {
        int count;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            count = 0;
            if (freq.containsKey(targetWord.charAt(i))) {
                count = freq.get(targetWord.charAt(i));
                freq.put(targetWord.charAt(i), ++count);
            } else {
                freq.put(targetWord.charAt(i), 1);
            }
        }
    }

    public void initGUI() {
        frame = new MyFrame("Wordle", 500, 600);

        MyPanel title = new MyPanel("Wordle", Color.BLACK);
        frame.add(title, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        MyPanel center = new MyPanel(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        center.setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 5));
        frame.add(center, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                entry[i][j] = new JLabel("", JLabel.CENTER);
                entry[i][j].setFont(new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.PLAIN, 24));
                entry[i][j].setSize(50, 50);
                entry[i][j].setLocation(i * 50 + 5, j * 50 + 5);
                entry[i][j].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
                entry[i][j].setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
                entry[i][j].setForeground(Color.WHITE);
                center.add(entry[i][j]);
            }
        }

        frame.addKeyListener(list = new KeyListener() {

            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                char ch = e.getKeyChar();
                String letter = Character.toString(ch);

                if (e.getExtendedKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE && letIndex > 0) {
                    letIndex--;
                    guessArray[letIndex] = "";
                    updateGuess("", entry[guessNum][letIndex]);

                } else if (e.getKeyChar() >= KeyEvent.VK_A && e.getKeyChar() <= KeyEvent.VK_Z && letIndex < 5) {
                    guessArray[letIndex] = letter;

                    updateGuess(letter, entry[guessNum][letIndex]);
                    letIndex++;

                } else if (e.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER && guessNum <= 5 && letIndex == 5) {
                    String guess = "";
                    for (int i = 0; i < guessArray.length; i++) {
                        guess += guessArray[i];
                    }
                    if (checkValid(guess) == true) {
                        submitGuess(guessArray, freq);
                        freq.putAll(revert);
                        guessNum++;
                        letIndex = 0;
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            }

        });

        frame.validate();
    }

    public void updateGuess(String letter, JLabel square) {
        square.setText(letter.toUpperCase());
    }

    private void submitGuess(String[] str, HashMap<Character, Integer> letFreq) {
        String arrToStr = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
            arrToStr += str[i];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { // GREEN LETTERS
            entry[guessNum][i].setFont(new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.BOLD, 20));
            entry[guessNum][i].setForeground(new Color(235,235,235));
            if (str[i].equals(Character.toString(targetWord.charAt(i)))) {
                letFreq.put(targetWord.charAt(i), letFreq.get(targetWord.charAt(i)) - 1);
                entry[guessNum][i].setBackground(new Color(20, 160, 20));
                entry[guessNum][i].setOpaque(true);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { // YELLOW LETTERS
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                if (str[i].equals(Character.toString(targetWord.charAt(j)))
                        && !str[i].equals(Character.toString(targetWord.charAt(i)))
                        && letFreq.get(targetWord.charAt(j)) > 0) {
                    letFreq.put(targetWord.charAt(j), letFreq.get(targetWord.charAt(j)) - 1);
                    entry[guessNum][i].setBackground(new Color(220, 220, 0));
                    entry[guessNum][i].setOpaque(true);
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            guessArray[i] = "";
        }
        frame.validate();

        if (arrToStr.equals(targetWord)) {
            endGame("win");
            frame.removeKeyListener(list);
        }
        if (guessNum == 5 && !arrToStr.equals(targetWord)) {
            endGame("lose");
            frame.removeKeyListener(list);
        }
    }

    private void endGame(String result) {
        Object[] options = { "PLAY AGAIN", "QUIT" };
        int option = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "You " + result + "! The word was: " + targetWord, "Message",
                JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null, options, null);
        if (option == 0) {
            frame.dispose();
            main(null);
        } else {
            System.exit(0);
        }

    }

    public boolean checkValid(String word) {
        try {
            checker = new Scanner(allWords);
            while (checker.hasNext()) {
                if (checker.nextLine().toUpperCase().equals(word)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String laf = UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName();
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(laf);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
        }

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Wordle();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

MyFrame and MyPanel extend jframe and jpanel with some set preferences. The file "words.txt" is the list of possible answer words, and "valid-wordle-words.txt" is all possible 5 letter words (for guesses). If you wanted to test this you could set the target word to any arbitrary 5 letter word and remove the check for a valid word, replace Myframe and MYpanel with JFrame and JPanel (but you may have to set some preferences)